# How to rescue PG::NotNullViolation error in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR`. Can anyone tell me how can I rescue the `PG::NotNullViolation`?

```
begin
 x.save
rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
 puts "I get here"
end
```

But I want to rescue the exact error, do we have a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with regexp an error's message

```
begin
 x.save 
rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid => e
  if e.message =~ /^PG::NotNullViolation/
    puts 'Error!!!'
  end
  raise
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid => e
  if e.cause.is_a?(PG:: NotNullViolation)
    # do something
  end
end`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to re-raise the exception, when the message doesn't match. Otherwise there is not information about the unhandled exception, what might cause problems.